# Postgres ts_headline inconsistent behaviour

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have just stumbled over a weird behaviour in postgres ts_headline function (used for highlighting fulltext search results).
First I thought the simple dictionary does not play with highlighting as the below example shows (there should be `<b>` tags):

```
# SELECT ts_headline('simple', 'This is artificial text', to_tsquery('artificial'));
       ts_headline       
-------------------------
 This is artificial text
(1 row)
```

But a different word works fine...

```
# SELECT ts_headline('simple', 'some Word in', to_tsquery('Word'));
 ts_headline     
---------------------
 some <b>Word</b> in
(1 row)
```

Does anybody have an explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I noticed my mistake.
The to_tsquery function inside also needs to know which dictionary to use (aka use the simple one). By default it uses english stemming which produces this result:

```
SELECT to_tsquery('artificial');
 to_tsquery 
------------
 'artifici'
```

which of course can not be found in the text converted by simple dictionary.
So the correct query would have been:

```
# SELECT ts_headline('simple', 'This is artificial text', to_tsquery('simple', 'artificial'));
          ts_headline           
--------------------------------
 This is <b>artificial</b> text
(1 row)
```

Comment: Good catch. Always set the regconfig. Most tutorials neglect this sadly

Comment: I just stumbled across this, but in reverse: the `to_tsquery` calls were set to a custom dictionary but the `ts_headline` call didn't set the same and I didn't realize it wouldn't inherit that value.  Make sure to provide a consistent dictionary definition on each call.